# images not showing / displaying after moving to server

Tags: javascript, deployment, server

I tried to find the answer to this problem - but had no luck finding it yet.

I moved a site to to the server. All is working fine - just the images are not showing up.

I know it is a (relative) path problem- but how to solve it??

Comment: obviously the server setups are not identical.

Comment: you should add more details, otherwise the question is too broad.

Comment: Open your browser console and check are you getting any "Not found error"?

Comment: "_I know it is a (relative) path problem- but how to solve it?_" Use the correct path instead of an incorrect one?

Comment: yes am getting not found error

Comment: my path is AboveoTestsite/img/bg/imagename

Comment: http://avdservicesinc.com/AboveoTest/img/bg/coco_gray.png

Comment: I found the error in console it is taking the path like http://avdservicesinc.com/img/bg/Servilence_gray.png

Comment: We need to see some code, some html from the page. What is the file path when you open the console and find the image that is working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome simple press `f12` and look at the console tab, you should see some red errors stating that an image could not be loaded, then looking at the file path you can see what exactly is going wrong

Chrome console should look something like this [image]